# Replicating Cell formula in Excel through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, reference

I want to create the IF formula in column C within VBA. However, when I do it, the formula comes out as using values of the cells rather than the cell reference. I want to know how to use cell reference:

[Have the formula say `[=IF(B2>0,2,A2)]` rather than `[=IF(1>0,2,1]` in my excel sheet for cell C2 when the VBA is ran.]

[image: Picture of worksheet I want to recreate. The formula is in column c]

```
Dim c As Range
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer

'//loop it in column C
For Each c In Range(Range("C2"), Range("C2").End(xlDown))
    a = c.Offset(0, -1) '// Column B
    b = c.Offset(0, -2) '// Column A
    c.Formula = "=IF(" & b & ">0,2," & a & ")" '// same format as formula [=IF(B2>0,2,A2)]
   
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
Dim a As Range
Dim b As Range

Set b = c.Offset(0, -1) '// Column B
Set a = c.Offset(0, -2) '// Column A

c.Formula = "=IF(" & b.Address(False,False) & ">0,2," & a.Address(False,False) & ")"
```

But you can accomplish this without looping or using the `Address`; Excel will update the relative references as the formula is filled down the column.

```
With ActiveSheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("C2:C" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(B2>0,2,A2)"
End With
```

Comment: No, the formula would change C2 would be `=IF(B2>0,2,A2)`,but C3 would be `=IF(B3>0,2,A3)`

Comment: Excel updates the relative references as the formula is filled down the column, please try it.